# cdf dashboard error processing component

Tags: pentaho

i am working with the cdf dashboards. When I open the cdf dashboard first time on every day, there is two components that returns Error processing component. But when I refresh the page, it loads the data normally.below are the pentaho logs

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 62,503,037 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 62,503,038 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the error message, you need to change the settings for your JDBC connection to mysql. You need to set autoReconnect=true so that the connections in the connection pool reconnect when they've been idle for a long time.